# Error finding module controller in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller, zend-framework2

I'm running into an issue where when I link to my module the controller throws an error:

`Fatal error: Class 'Rooms\Controller\RoomController' not found in C:\wamp\www\smtest\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager.php on line 170`

Now I'm still new to ZF2 but I'm under the understanding that this means that my module has an error in name spaces or in the autoloader, that being said heres that information:

module.config controller routes

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Rooms\Controller\Room' => 'Rooms\Controller\RoomController',
    ),
),
```

module.php

```
namespace Rooms;

class Module
{
public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';   
}

public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
}
```

RoomController.php

```
namespace Rooms\Controller;

class RoomsController extends AbstractActionController
{
private $usersTable;

//retrieve
public function indexAction()
{
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

link to module from homepage

```
$this->url('room/default', array('controller' => 'room', 'action' => 'index'))
```

Every similar question here on stack overflow or elsewhere has not resolved this issue, I've spent hours trying to fix this one issue, I coppied the module directly from another one in another part of my app that work, stripped it down then modified it so i didnt have to change as much and run into these issues.

Comment: is the extra `s` in `class RoomsController` a copy-paste typo or also in your original code? Because that could explain the error

Comment: @Pankrates its intentionale, the actual name of the module is `Rooms`

Comment: fair enough, but the invokable still has to match the exact controller class name. See my answer. You can keep `class RoomsController` but then you have to set the invokable class to `'Rooms\Controller\RoomsController'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of the `invokables` controller `RoomController`

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Rooms\Controller\Room' => 'Rooms\Controller\RoomController',
    ),
),
```

does not match the class name of your controller `RoomsController`

```
namespace Rooms\Controller;

class RoomsController extends AbstractActionController
{
```

changing the latter to `class RoomController` should fix the error

Comment: I truly don't think I understand it, but it sure did work! thanks much.

Comment: I do understand actually, makes perfect sense just a copy and paste error.

Comment: as I suspected, but those can sometimes be the worst to track down :) Glad it solved your problem